# How to create security groups across all OUs in AD

Tags: powershell, foreach, scripting, active-directory, ou

In my task it is necessary to create groups according to the OU name, taking into account nesting.

For example, there is such an OU

```
OU=Credential,OU=DepIT,DC=Contoso,DC=loc
```

then I need to create the following groups:

- In `DepIT`: Three groups `DepIT_R`, `DepIT_W`, `DepIT_L`
- In `Credential`: Two groups `DepIT_Credential_R`, `DepIT_Credential_W`

Finally, `DepIT_Credential_R` and `DepIT_Credential_W` must be members of `DepIT_L`.

Now the structure is as follows: OU `DepIT`, in it OU `Credential`. I have prepared screenshots of what I would like to do:

[image: 1. DepIT - structure]

[image: 2. DepIT - structure and groups]

[image: 3. Credential - groups]

[image: 4. DepIT_L group members]

My attempt so far:

```
$OU = "OU=DepIT,DC=Contoso,DC=loc"
$one_level_OU = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase $OU -SearchScope OneLevel -filter *


$one_level_OU | 

foreach{

New-ADGroup -Name $($_.Name+"_RW") -GroupCategory Security -groupscope global -Path $_.DistinguishedName
New-ADGroup -Name $($_.Name+"_R") -GroupCategory Security -groupscope global -Path $_.DistinguishedName
New-ADGroup -Name $($_.Name+"_L") -GroupCategory Security -groupscope global -Path $_.DistinguishedName

    $ous = Get-ADOrganizationalUnit -SearchBase "OU=$($_.name),OU=DepIT,DC=Contoso,DC=loc" -SearchScope Subtree -filter "name -notlike '*$($one_level_OU.Name)*'"

    $group_L = get-adgroup -Filter "name -like '*_L'" -Properties * | select name

    $ous | foreach {

       New-ADGroup -Name $($_.Name+"_RW") -GroupCategory Security -groupscope global -Path $_.DistinguishedName
       New-ADGroup -Name $($_.Name+"_R") -GroupCategory Security -groupscope global -Path $_.DistinguishedName


       foreach ($gr in $group_L) {
            Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $($_.name) -Members "$($_.Name+"_RW")", "$($_.Name+"_R")"
       }
    }
}
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: @Tomalak I added screenshots to the description to make it clearer.
Sorry my English is very poor.

Comment: Ah, now it' is clearer to me. I've updated your question with (I think) better wording.

Comment: You are adding a lot of space characters in the definitions for the OU's that should **NOT** be there. If not sure, right-click the OU of choice in ADUC, select properties en find/copy the real `distinguishedName` property. With these spaces, the second line in your code would retrieve nothing in `$one_level_OU`